# Speech Recognition doesn't do .onend function in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I am using the Web Speech API for speech recognition and it works perfectly fine in Chrome. However when I test it in Edge it doesn't call the `.onend` function.

Here's a quick demo. Note that you will need to use Edge to test the problem, the latest version that works with Web speech API.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
if (('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;

  jQuery(document).on("click", ".start_button", function(e) {
    recognition.start();
  });

  jQuery(document).on("click", ".stop_button", function(e) {
    recognition.stop();
  });

  recognition.onstart = function() {
    alert('started');
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    alert('ended');
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start_button">start</button>
<button class="stop_button">stop</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y1mLepft/

Comment: Is onstart firing? (I do not have Edge)

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes onstart works, I managed to get the .onend to work if you use abort() but Edge still doesn't seem to recognise speech.

Comment: Are you using Edge Chromium? I found that the `onend` event will be fired automatically a few moment after clicking the start button and won't be fired with `stop()` method. But I tried with `abort()` method, the `onend` event will be fired: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqBw.gif.

Comment: @YuZhou Yes abort works in terms of stopping the recording, but the voice to text doesn't work. It doesn't add any text to the textbox

Comment: If you must use `stop()` method, it seems to have some issue in Edge Chromium. I'll discuss with senior engineers and provide feedback about this issue. I'll inform you at the first time if there's any update about the issue.

Comment: I discussed with other senior engineers and reproduced the issue. It is a potential issue. You can provide your feedback to Edge Chromium and open an issue in [Web Speech API GitHub](https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/).